# WinSCP skip file deleted during operation

Tags: ms-access, ftp, winscp

I have a button in MS Access that creates a folder with some images, PDFs, and an Access .mdb file, and then opens WinSCP to run a command to upload the folder to an FTP server.

A problem I'm having though is that every now and then the upload fails due to "missing .ldb file". Basically what's happening is that when the .mdb is created Access temporarily creates it's locking .ldb file, and sometimes that .ldb file doesn't disappear until after WinSCP starts running. WinSCP then goes through all of the files uploading them, gets to the .ldb, and fails due to it not existing anymore.

At first I figured excluding .ldb files would work, but it doesn't.

So now I think just skipping non-existent files is the easiest solution.

Is this possible?

(Maybe even a delay at the start of the script as another solution?)

The code to upload:

```
Dim strSFTPDir As String
strSFTPDir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\"
Dim UploadsDir As String
UploadsDir = DLookup("PathToPics", "Admin") & "\Uploads\*"
Call Shell(strSFTPDir & "winscp.com /log=""C:\-TabletSoftware-\TabletBE\upload.log"" /command ""open ftp://username:password@ip/"" ""put -filemask=|*.ldb " & UploadsDir & " "" ""exit"" ", vbNormalFocus)
```

Also, another thing that would be helpful is if anyone knows how to use directories that contain spaces.

---

Edit: Okay I *think* I have it working, but since the error originally only happened occasionally, only time will tell.
The fix is in Access just before running WinSCP. It's simply a loop until the .ldb is removed.

```
Do While (Dir(StnPth & "\To Mail.ldb") <> "")
Loop
```

Comment: Please share your code. Are you trying to get a database to upload itself?

Comment: It's a completely separate database created in a folder with certain data imported into it. The code to open WinSCP runs just after the database is finished with being created, which is why it picks up the .ldb sometimes just before it disappears.

Comment: Why excluding .ldb does not work? Show us a WinSCP session log file for that.

Comment: Excluding .ldb files does work, I tested it by copying an ldb file into the uploads folder and in the log it says it's excluded, but it doesn't solve the problem of it failing on a .ldb file that was deleted while WinSCP is running. I assume that's because WinSCP works by at first listing everything to be uploaded, and then works through that list afterwards, excluding as it goes along?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use WinSCP 5.15, if you need it to [handle correctly](https://winscp.net/tracker/1677) a situation, when a file is selected for a file transfer (the `*` in `UploadsDir`), but excluded by an exclude mask (`-filemask=|*.ldb`), yet deleted after the `put` starts, but before WinSCP gets to that file.

---

If you are stuck with an older version of WinSCP, you can select only the files you need, instead of selecting all, and then excluding some.

It's easier to use [`lcd` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_lcd) to change working directory to `UploadsDir` (without `*`), so that you can then only enumerate positive file masks in the [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put).

[With multiple masks, you need to use target folder at the end](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#remarks) (use `./` to upload to the current working directory).

```vb
UploadsDir = DLookup("PathToPics", "Admin") & "\Uploads"

Call Shell(... """lcd " + UploadsDir + """ ""put *.mdb *.other *.yetanother ./"" ""exit"" ", ...)
```

Comment: Thanks. If my loop doesn't work out well then I'll look into doing it this way. In fact yours is probably a better solution anyway so if I have some spare time I may give it a go.

Comment: WinSCP 5.14 beta was released.